# Windows 10 search - disable "Search my stuff"

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, cortana

The way I used to start applications on Windows 7 is to press the Windows key, type a few letters of the application's name and press Enter. Even if finding the application took a bit longer, Search would defer processing the Enter key until the first results were there, and the desired application would launch.

In Windows 10, the search menu always has a default option to "Search my stuff", which opens an advanced search results window. This option is always there as the first entry before any actual results start showing up, so if I press Enter a fraction of a second before the application I want to launch shows up in the results, I'll go to "Search my stuff" instead. In that window, search takes a lot longer (e.g. finding "Paint" takes about 2 seconds in the Start menu search, but about 10 seconds in Find my stuff), and it doesn't allow selecting results by keyboard, I actually have to move to the mouse to select one.

Is there a way to completely remove the "Find my stuff" entry from the Start menu search results to get rid of this nuisance?

Comment: Have you disabled Cortana or performed any actions that might have disabled the "spying" in Windows 10.  These actions can play havoc on Windows Search if not done properly.  A screenshot would be helpful, there are about 20 "Windows 10" search questions on Superuser, I have my doubts, their answer(s) don't address your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound It's not really a fault, I believe search works as intended, except that the default behaviour is highly irritating to me and I wonder if it can be changed. I do get the correct results and in reasonable time (similar to Win7), but the new default action makes it very cumbersome to use. What I'm referring to is this: http://imgur.com/Rj5nEpq — this is the default entry that is always there before the actual results, and messes up the Return key handling. I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of it and have only actual results appear in the list, as it was in Windows 7.

Comment: The only answer I have is to use a third-party program to modify the start menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you felt more comfortable with the Win7 start menu I recommend to install Classic Shell. It allows you to use one of several versions (XP, Vista, Seven and derivatives of them) and at the same time keep the original start menu of Win10 (e.g. using ).

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: As there doesn't seem to be any way of achieving this without installing third-party software, I'll accept this as the answer. Thank you!